# Function inside Ajax success - Cordova/Framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, html-framework-7

I want to get a value from JSON and use in a function, inside an Ajax request:

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('device ready');

        function Hi(img_url){
            alert('Hi, the img_url is '+img_url);
        }
}
```

The ajax request:

```
$$.ajax({                 
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url: target,
                  //Sucess
                  success: function(data){
                    var img_url = data.media.display_src;
                    Hi(img_url);
                    },

                  //Error
                error: function(xhr,status){
                    alert("Error"+status+xhr);
                    console.log(xhr.response); 
                }
            });
```

But the function `Hi()` is always'undefined'...What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `Hi` function is inside another scope. Every `function` creates it's **own scope**, so what is defined in that `scope`, is `undefined` for another's. Move your function out from the `onDeviceReady` function.

**Example**

Here you will see that `innerFunction` and `innerVariable` are `undefined`, because they are not visible outside of `outer` function.

```js
function outer(){
  
  var innerVariable = 'hello';
  
  function innerFunction(){
    console.log('inner function')  ;
  }
  
}

console.log(innerVariable);
innerFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define `Hi()` outside the `onDeviceReady()` function.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function Hi(img_url){
  alert('Hi, the img_url is '+img_url);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
  alert('device ready');

}
```

In javascript you can't use a function outside the scope it was defined. Here is a detailed description of scope in JS: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)